# How to expose an application running on IPv6 protocol with network load balancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6, aws-nlb

I have an application which is running on a port 7071 and when I do:-

`netstat -aon | grep 7071`

I get:-

`tcp6 :::7071 3204/java (snipped)`

I am able to create a target group with tcp:7071 and host returns healthy and I have created a dualstack NLB(internet-facing) for this.

Still when I try to access this inside EC2 instance of another AWS account, the connection times out:-

`telnet dualstack.name.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com 80`

The security group allows all traffic at 80 including ipv6.

We have four AWS accounts which serve different environments(dev, Test, Beta, Prod).
the application that is running can have only one instance of it due to license restrictions. so we need to expose this app to other AWS accounts and that's why this setup(which is not working).

Please help.

Comment: Have you a picture of your security group? Is the load balancer in a public subnet (a subnet with an internet gateway)?

Comment: we have a Landing zone setup where each environment is isolated from others through AWS Accounts. Yes NLB is in public subnet.